# \begin{alltt} inside \subfloat

Tags: indentation, subfloats, minipage

I am trying to use the `alltt` environment inside a `\subfloat` element, and inside a minipage. The problem is that if I use `\subfloat` the indented text looses its indentation. Do you know any solution?

Herein a snippet of my code:

```
\subfloat[Caption]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
{\tiny
\begin{alltt}
   content...
\end{alltt}
}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "indentation"? You example code doesn't show the problem accurately. Could you make it into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem and clearly shows what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

Use a save box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig,alltt}
\newsavebox{\allttbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{lrbox}{\allttbox}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\tiny
\begin{alltt}
aaa
  This is in alltt
bbb
\end{alltt}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
\subfloat[Caption]{\usebox{\allttbox}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the even more powerful `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,alltt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\tiny
\begin{alltt}
aaa
  This is in alltt
bbb
\end{alltt}
\caption{Caption}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```