# \begin{alltt} inside subfigure in llncs

Tags: subfloats, lncs

I am trying to put some code in an alltt environment, in a subfigure in LLNCS documentclass.

I was previously using another documentclass which supported the subcaption package just fine, but when changing it to llncs, the subcaption package outputs

```
The `subcaption' package does not work correctly in compatibility mode.
```

So I think I am bound to use a \subfloat in the subfig package. Unfortunately, I could not get it working, and the answer at the similar question [\begin{alltt} inside \subfloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187333/beginalltt-inside-subfloat) is not quite satisfactory for me: would I have to use n saveboxes, one for each subfig in the figure?

Also, I think the main problem here is the next error that happens if I replace subcaption with subfig as per the previously linked question:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item
```

Comment: The problem is that `alltt` cannot go in the argument to another command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [[1](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-errmissitem.html)] that the altt environment uses an internal list, and that floats do not place nice with it.

So, it seems that the walkaround is to embed the alltt text inside a minipage, like so:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \subfloat[Subcaption here]{\label{fig:example:mwe}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{alltt}\scriptsize
      your altt text goes here
      \end{alltt}
    \end{minipage}
  }
\caption{The whole figure's caption. Can refer to \ref{fig:example:mwe}.}
\end{figure}
```